# i am trying to connect mysql using bottle.py, but it is showing error

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python, bottle

I followed this link : "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bottle-mysql/0.1.1"

and "http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/"

this is my py file:

```
import bottle
from bottle import route, run, template
import bottle_mysql

app = bottle.Bottle()
# # dbhost is optional, default is localhost
plugin = bottle_mysql.Plugin(dbuser='root', dbpass='root', dbname='delhipoc')
app.install(plugin)
@route('/hai/<name>')

def show(name,dbname):
    dbname.execute('SELECT id from poc_people where name="%s"', (name))
    print "i am in show"
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!',name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

this is my code and it is throwing error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 764, i
return route.call(**args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1575,
rv = callback(*a, **ka)
TypeError: show() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

please help me

Comment: I'm suffering the same with a hand-made plugin. The problem here is when setting up the plugin, the callbacks shows as having not args :(

I still can't get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with bottle-mysql, but in the example you provided:

```
@app.route('/show/:<tem>')
```

In your code:

```
@route('/hai/<name>')
```

It might expect:

```
@route('/hai/:<name>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.  Change this line:

```
def show(name,dbname):
```

to this:

```
def show(name, delhipoc):
```

---

Better yet, use `dbname = 'db'` and then

```
def show(name, db):
```

---

The MySQL plugin has chosen an unfortunate name for its db name param.  It would've been more clear to call it something like `db_parameter_name`, because what it actually refers to is the *name* of the db parameter in the decorated Python function.

Comment: @rothman. I just now tried what you have said but there is no use even i have changed to delhipoc or dbname or db . is is showing the same error.

Comment: @GopiKrishna: Are you sure you restarted your server?  This problem is clearly there in the code you posted.  The `dbname` must match the param name in your function.  If you want further help, please edit your question to include the modified code you're running now.  Thanks.

Comment: @rothman anyway thanks for the suggestion. i actually solved it by going through mysqldb.